# React / Flux: Should I have stores listen to other stores for changes?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I've built out a basic flux app for my first real world implementation.

Say I have a basic currency conversion app.

When I change the amount, or the currency to/from dropdowns I need to make ajax calls to
- 1) refetch currency info, and
- 2) recalculate the conversion rates.

I have a **rate store**, and a **currencyInfo store**.

**Here's my biggest hangup**:
 How do I tell the stores to refetch the data based on the various UI pieces / other store data changing?

These updates should happen in order as well, so
- 1) Update UI state
- 2) fetch Currency Info & update state / UI  3) fetch conversion, make calculation and update state / UI with final numbers.

**Options I see**:
a) (blech) ViewActionCreator.changeAmount(), changeFromCurrency(), changeToCurrency(), all API.fetchCurrency(), and then API.fetchConversion() and hope the ajax calls come back in the right order or try to figure out waitFor
b) Have the conversionStore and currencyStore listen to changes to the amountStore and then refetch their own data
c) ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue. But I can only speak for the setup I work with. The app components listen to the store and the UI components can call on actions. Those actions make the ajax call and then communicate with the store (calling on an update method). Then the store is updated, the app component hears it and pulls the latest state from the store with a setState, and re-renders accordingly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check out the waitFor() method in the flux dispatcher. It allows you to specify the order in which stores update in response to actions.

Facebook's chat app has a good example of this, where one store waits for two other stores to finish updating before it updates in response to an action.

https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/UnreadThreadStore.js

Comment: Accepting your answer because the links helped. Wound up going with Redux which simplified a lot of these issues.